# Pyspark Streaming with Pandas UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, pandas-groupby

I am new to Spark Streaming and Pandas UDF. I am working on pyspark consumer from kafka, payload is of xml format and trying to parse the incoming xml by applying pandas udf

```
@pandas_udf("col1 string, col2 string",PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def test_udf(df):
    import xmltodict
    from collections import MutableMapping 
    xml_str=df.iloc[0,0]
    df_col=['col1', 'col2']
    doc=xmltodict.parse(xml_str,dict_constructor=dict)
    extract_needed_fields = { k:doc[k] for k in df_col }
    return pd.DataFrame( [{'col1': 'abc', 'col2': 'def'}] , index=[0] , dtype="string" )

data=df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) AS value") 
data.groupby("value").apply(test_udf).writeStream.format("console").start()
```

I get the below error

```
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 859, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 215, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 104, in pyarrow.lib._handle_arrow_array_protocol
ValueError: Cannot specify a mask or a size when passing an object that is converted with the __arrow_array__ protocol.
```

Is this the right approach ? What am i doing wrong

Comment: looks like a bug in spark: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31920

Comment: Seems like, this was fixed for 3.3.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34521

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, as if this is a more kind of undocumented limitation than a bug.
You cannot use any pandas type which will be stored as an array object, which has a method named `__arrow_array__`, because [pyspark always defines a mask](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a07df1acc662d8c85c7f6e53a08d011056998072/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py#L163). The `string`  type you used, is stored in a StringArray, which is [such a case](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/search?q=__arrow_array__). After I converted the string dtype into object, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

While converting a pandas dataframe to a pyspark one, I stumbled upon this error as well :

```
Cannot specify a mask or a size when passing an object that is converted with the __arrow_array__ protocol
```

My pandas dataframe had datetime-like values that I tried to convert to "string". I initially used the `astype("string")` method, which looked like this :

```py
df["time"] = (df["datetime"].dt.time).astype("string")
```

When I tried to get the info of this dataframe, it seemed like it was indeed converted to a string type :

```py
df.info(verbose=True)
> ...
>  #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype
> ...
>  6   time      295452 non-null  string
```

But the error kept coming back to me.

### Solution

To avoid it, I instead went on to use the `apply(str)` method :

```py
df["time"] = (df["datetime"].dt.time).apply(str)
```

Which gave me a type of `object`

```py
df.info(verbose=True)
> ...
>  #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype
> ...
>  6   time      295452 non-null  object
```

After that, the conversion was successful

```py
spark.createDataFrame(df)
# DataFrame[datetime: string, date: string, year: bigint, month: bigint, day: bigint, day_name: string, time: string, hour: bigint, minute: bigint]
```

Comment: Had the same issue, this seemed to work, using ```.apply(str)``` rather than ```.astype(string)```